# Prevent Text Wrap in DataGrid

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with a data-bound DataGrid control, in that despite each column having its Wrap property set to false, the text still wraps.  It seems to only do this on IE, and not FF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Microsoft is aware of this issue and they have [provided a workaround](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=104081)...

I don't know if this was addressed in IE8 B2... you might try it and see. Good luck!